# Find elements within a specific MongoDB document's array

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I think what I am trying to do is fairly simple, but I may be phrasing it incorrectly because I can't find the answer anywhere. I have a MongoDB schema that looks like this:

```
{
    title: "some movie"
    tickets: [
        {
            isSold: false,
            id: 1,
        },
        {
            isSold: true,
            id: 2,
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to 1) find the document based solely on the `title` property; and 2) once the document is found, *then* query the array to find all elements of that array where `isSold` is true. Is it possible to do this with MongoDB queries and without having to use some kind of for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the document and use the `$filter` operator to filter the element in the `tickets` array in the projection.

```
db.collection.find({
  title: "some movie",
  "tickets.isSold": true
},
{
  title: 1,
  tickets: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$tickets",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$this.isSold",
          true
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ttkdwYOshbZ)